# Reload GET after error in POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In the POST function, if the quantity contains a 'letter' i want to reload the GET.
I've tried the `return View();` and looked at the `return Redirect(returnUrl);` but the URL has too many paramaters. Cant I simply reload the GET EDITDETAIL

```
 [Authorize]
    public ActionResult EditDetail(int id, string returnUrl)
    {
        var order = _orderService.GetOrder(id);



 [HttpPost, ActionName("EditDetail"), Authorize]
    public ActionResult EditDetailPOST(int customerId, int? orderId, List<string> productId, List<string> quantity, string returnUrl, string TargetDate)
    {
        QBCustomerRecord customer = _customerService.GetById(customerId);
        if (customer == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The customer id is Invalid.");
        }

        bool quantityContainsLetter = quantity.Any(s => s.Any(Char.IsLetter));

        if (quantityContainsLetter)
        {
            _notifier.Information(T("A letter has been entered for quantity. Please enter a number"));

            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Do you need to show some validation when qantityContainsLetter? for that why you need to redirect?

Comment: yeah if the quantity contains letters I want to reload the page with the error :A letter has bee entered...

Comment: Why do you need to reload the data again for validation? You keep the same data and show some error messages to correct.

Comment: thats what i am trying to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call [RedirectToAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492939%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

`return RedirectToAction("EditDetail", new { id = 23, returnUrl = "" });`

to execute the GET version of `EditDetail`. Forgive me if I've got the `RouteValueCollection` setup wrong, I'm doing this answer very quickly before I go to a meeting! :)

EDIT:

OK, I misread your requirement. In order to show the EditDetail view that was shown from the GET call, you will have to call:

`return View("EditDetail")`

I'm assuming that's the name of the view, since your code is missing the `return` statement in the GET version of EditDetail.

Also, for the POST method, you can do this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult EditDetail(int customerId, int? orderId, List<string> productId, List<string> quantity, string returnUrl, string TargetDate)
```

Since that method's signature is different to the GET version, you can overload the method by using the same name. No need for the `ActionName` attribute. If you do this, then you can call

`return View();`

In the POST method, without having to pass the view name.

Comment: Looks like OP is doing some validation and want to show it in the view. For this why we need redirection?